# After firebase hosting, I got error "firebase is not defined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

After firebase hosting , I got error "firebase is not defined".
I tried using api key but It doesn't work too.

I pasted the below code to my index.html

```
<!-- update the version number as needed -->
<script defer src="/__/firebase/7.4.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
<script defer src="/__/firebase/7.4.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/7.4.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/7.4.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/7.4.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>
<!-- initialize the SDK after all desired features are loaded -->
<script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/sessionchk.js"></script>
```

sessionchk.js >>

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
            document.getElementById("loginmenu").textContent = "logout";
            document.getElementById("loginmenu").href = "/logout";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("loginmenu").textContent = "login";
            document.getElementById("loginmenu").href = "/loginform";
        }
    });
```

what am I missing now???

Comment: is firebase available as mentioned in the source of script in your project folders ??

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `defer` attribute to your `<script>` tag -- as-is it is loading before the rest of the scripts.

Comment: Yes, even your custom script.